# passing parameter to DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

i am working on application in WP7 , i would like to pass a list box as parameter to client_DownloadStringCompleted method.

My code looks like below ,

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this line to your code:

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(yourUri, yourListBox);
```

Comment: How will i access this listbox in the method ?

Comment: The listbox will be in the `UserState` property of the `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs` passed to the event handler.  Youo can get it with:  `ListBox lb = (ListBox)e.UserState;`

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thank you guys ! Also i wanted to know that what if i want to pass more than one parameter to this event handler ?

Comment: The UserState is of type `Object`. That means you can pass anything you want into it. If you need more than one thing passed in, then pass in an object array: `object[] { param1, param2 }`