# DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler Parameters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events, parameters, windows-phone-7.1

I have this following method that calls a webservice. The DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler 'callback' is obviously the the function control will flow to after this function completes:

```
private void myWebService(string yourParameter, DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback)
{
    //Url to search servlet
    string servletUrl = string.Format("https://something.com/etc/what?bla={0}",
        Uri.EscapeDataString(yourParameter));

    //Calls Servlet
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += callback;
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(servletUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

I call the above function like so:

```
myWebService("Hello there!", myWebServiceReturn);
```

WebServiceReturn (where control will end up after the webservice call) then looks like this:

```
private void myWebServiceReturn(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //And here we end up...
    //how do I get the value of 'yourParameter' that I sent to 'myWebService()'??
}
```

So my question is.. The parameter that I sent to 'myWebService()', in this case 'yourParameter', how do I get that very same value in the 'myWebServiceReturn' method? If I could somehow attach that to the 'DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e' and retrieve it that way that would be very convenient.

Would really appreciate anyones help!! :(

Comment: UPDATE - So I found something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048371/passing-parameter-to-downloadstringcompletedeventhandler-in-c-sharp?rq=1 But say I do it this way, what on earth would the 'Uri' be of my 'yourParameter' ?

Comment: think this is pretty much what you want... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this overload of [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144203.aspx). It takes an extra parameter of type object which is available in the completed handler via the UserState property of the DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.
This allows you to pass in any state information you want.

e.g. Calling the service:

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(servletUrl, UriKind.Absolute), yourParameter);
```

Accessing the result:

```
string yourParameter = e.UserState as string;
```

Comment: Ahh! There's already an overload?? I almost went and wrote my own! This worked btw, thank you so so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the callback method, you have reference to the sender object. In your myWebservice, add a header in the client object-

```
client.Headers["yourParameter"]= yourParameter;
```

and inside your call back, you can retrieve the header like this

```
var client= sender as WebClient;
string parameter= client.Headers["yourParameter"];
```

Edit: This is obviously not the right way to identify the asynchronous request. sga101's method is more appropriate.